# Set the panel visible property true falls in static method

Tags: c#, winforms

Here i have a panel control and i want to set it's visible property true or False in static method. Is it possible to do that.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(404, 317);
this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
this.panel1.TabIndex = 3;


    public static void setPanelVisible(bool blnVisible)
            {
                panel1.Visible = blnVisible;
            }
```

Comment: Unless the panel1 member is also static, or you pass panel1 into the method, no.

Comment: Why do you need it?

Answer (score 2):

In a  `static` method, you can only set properties to `static` controls. So if you want to set a property to your panel using a `static` method, the panel should be declared as `static` itself:

```
private static System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
```

---

Another option is to pass the control itself as a parameter to your  `static` method:

```
public static void setPanelVisible(bool blnVisible, System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel)
{
    panel.Visible = blnVisible;
}
```